# issue with passing data to onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, object, android-activity

im attempting to send a string from one of my activities to the main activity of the group, but am having a small issue. Im attempting to create an object in the onActivityResult part of my code(which seems to work). but when trying to access methods from this class other than getName(), it spits out a resource not found exception. Im sure the solution is simple, but it continues to elude me after looking into it a fair bit. heres the code....

**MainActivity**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
   {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       switch(requestCode)
       {
       case 0:
           //for add activity
           if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
           {

                        namePasser = data.getExtras().getString("tallyName").toString();
                        itemHm.put("item1", new Items(namePasser,1));
                        itemAmt++;
                        currItem = itemHm.get("item1");
                        nameView1.setText(currItem.getName());
                        countView1.setText(currItem.getGroup());
                        count1b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        reduce1b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        countView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        resetb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

           }
       }
   }
```

**addActivity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class addActivity extends Activity
{
    EditText name;
    String itemName;
    Button next;
    Intent data;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addactivityxml);
        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
                name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newitemtxt);
                itemName = name.getText().toString();
                data = new Intent();
                data.putExtra("tallyName", itemName);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Items Class**

```
public class Items
{
    int id = 0;
    int group = 0;
    String name = "";
    int count = 0;
    public Items(String name, int count)
    {
        this.count = count;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Items(String name, int count, int group)
    {
        this.group = group;
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
    }
    public Items(int id, String name, int group)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.group = group;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }
    public int addCount()
    {
        count++;
        return count;
    }
    public int reduceCount()
    {
        if(count > 0)
        {
            count--;
            return count;
        }
        return count;
    }
    public int resetCount()
    {
        count = 0;
        return count;
    }
    public void setGroup(int group)
    {
        this.group = group;
    }
    public int getGroup()
    {
        return group;
    }
}
```

The data itself is being passed through to onActivity Result when i run
nameView1.setText(currItem.getName());
eiyhout a problem,

but when trying to run
countView1.setText(currItem.getGroup());
thats when the issue occurs

oh! heres the error log

> 04-19 11:09:56.219: W/dalvikvm(1970): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.DanielFurnell.iTallyLite/com.DanielFurnell.iTallyLite.ITallyLiteActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2980)
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3023)
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:123)
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1177)
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:247)
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3473)
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970):     at com.DanielFurnell.iTallyLite.ITallyLiteActivity.onActivityResult(ITallyLiteActivity.java:73)
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2976)
>   04-19 11:09:56.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1970):     ... 11 more

I am also quite sure there isnt anything wrong with the textbox of the item as i can assign other values to it outside of ActivityResult
Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me with this issue =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
countView1.setText(currItem.getGroup());
```

may be this line has problem, `getGroup` return the `int` type, it think is as the string id, **so you need check the return value is a valid string id or not**, if you only want to set the content with `getGroup` return, try use:

```
countView1.setText(currItem.getGroup()+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newitemtxt);
```

remove this line from click event and add below button next = ...

and try..